# Unable to get location using HTML5 on Safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari, geolocation

My website gets the location of most browsers but I found that it fails on Safari even though the connection is secure(HTTPS).
You could test it on Fullder.com by clicking on the red icon.
My code looks like this:

#### html.slim

```
button.share-location onclick="geoFindMe()"
```

#### JavaScript

```
function geoFindMe() {

    function success(position) {
        document.getElementById("latitude").value = position.coords.latitude;
        document.getElementById("longitude").value = position.coords.longitude;    
        $('#restaurant-search').submit();
    }

    function error() {
        alert("Unable to retrieve your location");
    }

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
};
```

I instantly get the "Unable to retrieve your location" error. Thank you for any suggestions on what might be the problem!